# Does the Release Preview version of Windows 8 not get any app updates?

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-store

I've noticed that several of my apps installed on Windows 8 are outdated and even though the app websites mention that they've been updated, none of the updates can be seen from the Windows Store.

Is this because I'm still running on the RP? Do I not get any app updates, now that Win 8 is in RTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App updates were provided only for the Windows GA (RTM) version. Windows 8 release preview  did get some security updates, but the feature updates were restricted to the final version.

I use the Windows 8 (Final/GA/RTM) version and hence received the updates. Noticeable to me were updates to SkyDrive.